# Why do I get duplicate toolbar entries?

Tags: django-cms

The django-cms cms_toolbar has duplicate items -

[image: screenshot of two items for each function]

It happens for me on django-cms 2.2 and the develop branch (2.2.post0). I'm running python 2.7.2, django 1.3.1

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you report bugs through the proper channel: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues and not on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem, it was because, I had `{% render_block "js" %}` this coding two times in the template.